# jquery using .nextUntil()

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to generate a jquery script to make all tr elements from a table with class top clickeable and when one tr with class top is clicked all tr below with class bt until there is another tr class top will slideToggle.

I tried several things, but none is working, I think I am having some problems with my selectors.

Could anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Also see example [here](http://jsbin.com/ateze5/edit)

One of the scripts I created is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("tr .top").click(function () {
  $('tr .bt').nextUntil('tr:not(.bt)').slideToggle("slow");
  )};
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
    <tr class="top">
      <td>top row 1</td>
      <td>top row 1</td>
      <td>top row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bt">
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bt">
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bt">
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="top">
      <td>top row 2</td>
      <td>top row 2</td>
      <td>top row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bt">
      <td>bt row 2</td>
      <td>bt row 2</td>
      <td>bt row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bt">
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
      <td>bt row 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs a few teaks, this:

```
$("tr .top").click(function () {
  $('tr .bt').nextUntil('tr:not(.bt)').slideToggle("slow");
  )};
```

Should be this:

```
$("tr.top").click(function () {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.bt)').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The class is *on* the `<tr>` not beneath is so no space there.  You want to start with `$(this)` (the clicked `<tr>`) when traversing, and the last `)};` is out of order, it should be `});` closing the function then then `.click()` call.

[Here's the updated/working version](http://jsbin.com/ateze5/2/edit), keep in mind slide toggling table rows gets messy, you may want to fade toggle instead, like this:

```
$("tr.top").click(function () {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.bt)').animate({ opacity: "toggle" });
});
```

[Test that version here](http://jsbin.com/ateze5/3).

Comment: Thank it works! Could you also let me know why in Chrome is adding an extra row when I click on top row?, Thanks again.

Comment: @Cesar - It's not doing that here, though the animation will be off when you `.slideToggle()` because of how a table is rendered... added a fading alternative for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("tr .top").click(function () {
  $('tr .bt').nextUntil('tr .top').slideToggle("slow");
  )};
```

i think it was works..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr.top").click(function () {
//   ^
  $('tr.bt').nextUntil('tr:not(.bt)').slideToggle("slow");
//     ^
// And I think you should use $(this) here instead of $('tr.bt')
//  otherwise you cannot toggle the first .bt row,
//  but all the rest will be toggled regardless of which group.
});
```

There should be no spaces between `tr` and the `.`.

```
"a .b"
```

matches all *descendent* of `a` which have class `b`, while

```
"a.b"
```

matches all `a` which have class `b`.

Comment: This still won't produce the desired effect of toggling local "child" rows...this will toggle on/off *all* "children", as opposed to those for the given `.top` parent :)