# jQuery .nextUntil() equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an alternative for jQuery's `.nextUntil()`. I'm currently using `jQuery 1.3.1` and updating it is out of the question :(

I have this HTML:

```
<h4>...</h4>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h4>...</h4>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

and I have this jQuery code:

```
$('h4').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h4').toggle();
});
```

but `.nextUntil()` is added in `1.4.0` So do you have an idea how to do that in `1.3.1` ?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/3943667/273200

Comment: Use a loop with a conditional statement.

Comment: @Bala R I saw taht, but it still uses `.nextUntil()`

Comment: You can run two versions of jQuery at once.. You'll keep the compatibility for your existing stuff, and still be able to use the newer features.

Comment: @jnpcl I know that, but its not a good solution I think :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('h4').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('h4')) { return false; }
        $(this).toggle();
    })
});
```

<s>Not tested.</s> Tested by @ingo :)

Answer (score 6):

You can emulate the behavior of [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) by using [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) together:

```
var $nextAll = $(this).nextAll();
$nextAll.slice(0, $nextAll.index("h4")).toggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
function nextUntil($start, until)
{
    var matches = [];

    for (var e = $start.next(); e.length !== 0 && !e.is(until); e = e.next())
    {
        matches.push(e);
    }
    return $(matches);
}
```

Or use `nextAll()`:

```
function nextUntil_v2($start, until)
{
    var matches = [];

    $start.nextAll().each(function ()
    {
        if ($(this).is(until)) return false;
        matches.push(this);
    });

    return $(matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
$('h4').click(function(){
    $n = $(this).next();
    while($n.is('h4') == false) {
        $n.toggle();
        $n = $n.next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs to use jQuery 1.3: There is the [jQuery Untils plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-untils), which got added to jQuery `1.4.0`:

> jQuery Untils provides three very simple, but very useful methods: nextUntil, prevUntil, and parentsUntil. These methods are based on their nextAll, prevAll, and parents counterparts, except that they allow you to stop when a certain selector is reached. Elements are returned in “traversal order”.
>
> ...
>
> Tested with jQuery 1.3.2 in Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 2-3.7, Safari 3-4, Chrome 4-5, Opera 9.6-10.1.